# Unsupported media type from Postman sending to ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple Web Api project set up, and I want to send the post request a string, but whatever I do I get "Unsupported Media Type". I am sending "value" with header "Content-Type": "text/plain".

This is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<string> Post([FromBody] string val) 
{
    return val + " success!";

}
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Post returns string ? `public void Post([FromBody] string value)`

Comment: ActionResult<string> returns a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ASP.NET Core 2.1 or later ,  [`[ApiController]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#apicontroller-attribute) is applied a controller class .It can automatically infer the `[FromBody]` binding source for your complex action method parameters. But [`[FromBody]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#frombody-inference-notes) isn't inferred for simple types such as string or int. Therefore, the `[FromBody]` attribute should be used for simple types when that functionality is needed.

So you could post a simple string with `Conten-Type:application/json` in postman like below:
[image]

Unfortunately ASP.NET Core doesn't let you just capture 'raw' data in any meaningful way just by way of method parameters. There are two ways that you could refer to read the raw data as shown:

1.The easiest and least intrusive, but not so obvious way to do this is to have a method that accepts POST or PUT data without parameters and then read the raw data from `Request.Body`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<string> Post() 
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
            var val = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
    return val + " success!";
}
```

2. Custom formatting of content using an `InputFormatter`.

```
public class RawRequestBodyFormatter : InputFormatter
{
    public RawRequestBodyFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allow text/plain, application/octet-stream and no content type to
    /// be processed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override Boolean CanRead(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        var contentType = context.HttpContext.Request.ContentType;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType) || contentType == "text/plain" ||
            contentType == "application/octet-stream")
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handle text/plain or no content type for string results
    /// Handle application/octet-stream for byte[] results
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        var contentType = context.HttpContext.Request.ContentType;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType) || contentType == "text/plain")
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body))
            {
                var content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                return await InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(content);
            }
        }
        return await InputFormatterResult.FailureAsync();
    }
}
```

The InputFormatter has to be registered with MVC in the ConfigureServices() startup code:

```
services.AddMvc(opts =>opts.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new RawRequestBodyFormatter()));
```

You could refer to [this blog](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/sep/14/accepting-raw-request-body-content-in-aspnet-core-api-controllers?page=2) for more details.